# Options for socket QModbusClient

Tags: qt, tcp

We are developing a client-server QT 5.15.2 application using QModbusClient (TCP) under linux. Faced with a problem: the ConnectedState status does not change if you pull the cable out of the network card. The state changes only after a long time (about 40 minutes). It was found that when creating a socket, you can specify parameters responsible for delays tcp_user_timeout, tcpkeepalive and others. But when we make a connection, we cannot specify such QModbusClient options. What solution can there be for such a situation?

```
void MainWindow::onStateChanged(int state)
  {
      bool connected = (state != QModbusDevice::UnconnectedState);
      ui->actionConnect->setEnabled(!connected);
      ui->actionDisconnect->setEnabled(connected);

      if (state == QModbusDevice::UnconnectedState)
          ui->connectButton->setText(tr("Connect"));
      else if (state == QModbusDevice::ConnectedState)
          ui->connectButton->setText(tr("Disconnect"));
  }
```